# ESBuild minification of AWS SDK causes high memory usage on Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, esbuild

I have a simple nodejs Lambda handler that imports aws-sdk module. I noticed that if I set minify to 'true' in ESBuild settings and bundle and minify my javascript file and run it on Lambda the Lambda uses around 240 MB of memory. When I set minify to false, memory usage at runtime is 100 MB.

What might be causing this and is there any way to fix the issue? Any ESBuild settings that might fix this?

The only module I import in my only js file (index.js) is aws-sdk as I'm debugging the cause of this issue and my code does nothing but a console.dir on the AWS object. So there is nothing in the code itself that might cause the issue.

**EDIT:**

When I bundle the code with minify set to true the size of the bundle is around 9 MB and memory usage when it is run on Lambda is 240 MB. When I set minify to false the bundled file is a bit over 20 MB but memory usage when I run it on Lambda is around 100 MB. So I would say that the file size is not the issue here but rather minification does something to the output code that causes more memory use at runtime. But I have no idea what that might be or if there might be an ESBuild setting to remedy this.

Comment: Are you minifying a server-side package? why? running esbuild takes memory, and having it do more takes more memory.

Comment: @user1852503 Normally you minify it before deploying… I’m not sure *why* it’d be minified, but pretty sure it’s not being minified as part of the lambda.

Comment: @user1852503 I'm bundling and minifying my AWS Lambda function code during its deployment to AWS. Mainly just so that the code is bundled with only the npm packages it needs instead of all I have in the repository. But would also be nice to minify the code. Issue is memory usage on the Lambda when I run the code, not during bundling/minification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is identifier minification that causes the issue. Instead of setting "minify: true/false" tried setting my options in my esbuild script [separately](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#minify) as

```
minifyWhitespace: true,
minifyIdentifiers: false,
minifySyntax: true
```

With minifyIdentifiers false memory usage is around 100 MB and with true it is 240 MB. So looks like some identifiers are mishandled. This only happens with aws-sdk package as far as I can tell. Not going to dig into aws-sdk more to see what the issue might be as I don't think I can do anything about it anyway. Slightly annoying to have to do this but oh well...

Comment: This has to be a bug in esbuild. In my project, I had the `minify` flag set to `true` and it broke the bundled functions. when I set the `minifyIdentifiers` to `false` it started to work again.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re emitting source maps, that may be the culprit. If you aren’t sure whether you are including source maps or not, you can usually see the source map in the Lambda console. You can view the esbuild sourcemap documentation [here](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#sourcemap)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I  checked and source maps are not included. In general I don't think the issue is the size of the resulting javascript bundle file but rather something happens to the code when I enable minification on ESBuild. I edited my original question to add a bit on this to the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output file, it might have the source maps inline.